# Regex - match any text between some delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to catch this string `[[....]]` (including brackets)

where `....` can be anything (including non-printable) except `]]`

Here is the source where to match :

```
var myString = 'blablablabla[["<strong>LA DEFENSE 4 TEMPS ( La Rotonde )</strong><br />Centre commercial LES 4 TEMPS",
                         48.89141725,
                         2.23478235,
                         "4T"],
    ["<strong>ANGERS</strong><br />Centre commercial GEANT",
                         48.89141725,
                         2.23478235,
                         "4T"]]blablablabla'
```

I try to use this method `[^\]]+` to match all chars/non-chars except double bracket. The problem i have is that i do not know how to use this method with a bracket that is immediatly after the first bracket `[^\]\]]+`.

Is there a solution with positive/negative lookahead or word boundary ?

```
(\[\[[^\](?=\])]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/B2ZsmrRfJQHOE5M1)

Any help please ?

Comment: You can use `/\[\[[\s\S]*?\]\]/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, to match any text between some delimiters that consist of more than one character is best achieved with the `[^]`/`[\s\S]`/`[\d\D]`/`[\w\W]` construct with a lazy quantifier (`*?` matching 0 or more occurrences, or `+?` matching 1 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern, but as few as possible to return a valid match).

While `[^]` construct matching any character including a newline is JavaScript specific, `[\s\S]` and its variants are mostly cross-platform constructs that will work in PCRE, .NET, Python, Java, etc. The `[...]` in this case is a character class that contains two *opposite* shorthand  classes. Since `\s` matches all whitespace characters and `\S` matches all non-whitespace characters, this `[\s\S]` matches *any* symbol there is in any input.

**I'd recommend to avoid using `(.|\n)`**. This construct causes more backtracking steps to occur and slows regex search down.

So, you can use

```
\[\[[\d\D]*?]]
```

See [JS regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bX0rO6/2)

Here is a code snippet:

```js
var re = /\[\[[\d\D]*?]]/g; 
var str = 'blablablabla[["<strong>LA DEFENSE 4 TEMPS ( La Rotonde )</strong><br />Centre commercial LES 4 TEMPS",\n                         48.89141725,\n                         2.23478235,\n                         "4T"],\n    ["<strong>ANGERS</strong><br />Centre commercial GEANT",\n                         48.89141725,\n                         2.23478235,\n                         "4T"]]blablablabla';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(m[0]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

In this case, when the delimiters are different and consist of just 2 characters, you can use a technique of matching all characters other than the first symbol of the closing delimiter and then 0 or more sequences of the whole closing delimiter followed by 1 or more occurrences of any symbol other than the first symbol in the closing delimiter.

```
\[\[[^\]]*(?:][^\]]+)*]]
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oW3sP1/1)

The linear character of this regex makes it really fast.

P.S. I also want to note that you do not need to escape the `]` outside of character class in JS regex, but it must be escaped inside a character class - always.

Comment: Thank you for yout solution/explanation @stribizhev

Comment: what does `[\s\S]/[\d\D]/[\w\W]` mean ?

Comment: I added an explanation of the idea of opposite shorthand classes inside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\[\[(.|\n)*?\]\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/gR5oJ3/1

It should match anything between and including `[[` `]]`.  The main issue was dealing with *newlines*, and the `(.|\n)` part will match anything **including newlines**.